# Correlating NSCalendar symbols with numeric constants

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

`NSCalendar` has properties for calendrical symbols like *month*, *era*, etc.:

```
var monthSymbols: [String] { get }
var eraSymbols: [String] { get }
…
```

What is the proper way to map them from and to the numeric constants that I need in `NSDateComponents`?

Answer (score 0):

I really hope there is actually a better way as this seems very wordy, but essentially this is just getting access to `monthSymbols` in NSCalendar.

```
let monthNumeric = 1 // January
let monthName = "January"

print(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().monthSymbols[monthNumeric-1])
print(NSCalendar.currentCalendar().monthSymbols.indexOf(monthName)! + 1)
```

<s>The same should apply for *eraSymbols*.</s>
Note that also that the **Swift Foundation** is evolving & the source is [public](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSCalendar.swift). As the API should largely match the *Darwin Foundation*, it is a good resource for looking under the covers.

Comment: The same **does not** apply for era symbols. The numeric constants for eras, unlike those for months, start at zero, at least in `NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601` calendars, presumably for `NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian` as well.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was oriented on the fact that _eraSymbols_, like _monthSymbols_ are essentially just an _Array_ of _Strings_. The contents, of course, will be different.

Comment: That they're arrays of strings I've already stated in my question, and that the contents are different is to be expected. You seemed to suggest that there is a direct relation between the string constant's index in the array and the numeric constant. But that relation is not the same across symbols. Sometimes I have to add `1` and sometimes I don't. I'm looking for a solution that works for **all** symbols in **all** calendars, and I don't want to write an exhaustive mapping function. A date and time API is supposed to spare me such exertions.